# write a new function that takes in a dataframe df as an argument and returns a pandas series summarizing that dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

Write a new function below called `summary_stats`that takes in a dataframe `df` as an argument and returns a pandas Series summarizing that dataframe. The pandas Series should have the following index and value pairs:

`mean_x`: the mean of the dataframe's `x` column, `df['x'].mean()`

`mean_y`: the mean of the dataframe's `y` column

`var_x`: the variance of the dataframe's `x` column

`var_y`: the variance of the dataframe's `y` column

`corr_xy`: the correlation of the dataframe's `x` and `y` columns (hint: you can call the pandas corr function on x and pass in y as an argument).

The code I had right now is:

```
ans = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
def summary_stats (df):
    mean_x = df['x'].mean()
    mean_y = df['y'].mean()
    var_x = df['x'].var()
    Vay_y = df['y'].var()
    corr_xy = df['x'].corr(df['y'])
```

I am confused on how to define a new function

Comment: "I am confused on how to define a new function" No, you are not; your code already correctly does this. What it does not do is a) create a `Series`, nor b) return it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should already do the work, you only need to add a `return` statement. If you want a pandas Series, then you need to specify that as well:

```
df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
def get_stats(df, col1, col2):

    return pd.Series([df[col1].mean(), df[col2].mean(), df[col1].var(), df[col2].var()])

Out:
0     9.000000
1     7.500682
2    10.232558
3     3.837388
dtype: float64
```

If instead you want it as a pandas DataFrame with the columns' names:

```
def get_stats(df, col1, col2):

    return pd.DataFrame({'mean':[df[col1].mean(),df[col2].mean()],
                         'var':[df[col1].var(),df[col2].var()]},
                       index=[col1,col2])


print(get_stats(df, 'x','y'))

Out:
       mean        var
x  9.000000  10.232558
y  7.500682   3.837388
```